# How to move to another slide after bullet appering?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a bulletted list with animation. So each time I press enter a new list item appears. The problem is for some items I need to display slides with detailed information. I want to do it the following way:

1. Press enter - bulletted list item appears
2. Press enter - detailed information slide appears
3. Press enter - we go back to list slide and see it in the state before goind to detailed slide
4. Press enter - next bulletted list item appears

Is there any way to do it with Power Point 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use VBA. You would need to intercept the Enter key and increment a counter. On the odd counts, AddEffect and on the even counts, GotoSlide.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb230693(v=office.12).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251172(v=office.12).aspx

It's actually View.GotoSlide in 2010 but the Library reference for 2007 is much more detailed. ApplyAnimation might be useful in 2010 as well, but again, the Library reference is lacking.